# What does RESTful web applications mean?

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest

A web service is a function that can be accessed by other programs over the web (Http). To clarify a bit, when you create a website in PHP that outputs HTML its target is the browser and by extension the human being reading the page in the browser. A web service is not targeted at humans but rather at other programs.

1. SOAP and REST are two ways of creating WebServices. Correct me if i
   am wrong?
2. What are other ways i can create a WebService?
3. What does it mean fully RESTful web Application?

Comment: This probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com or even on [Google](http://google.com).

Comment: Ad. 1
Not necessarily. The two ways are Big Web Services and RESTful Web Services. It's a bit more complicated than just using or not using SOAP. SOAP can be used in accordance with REST.

Ad. 3
Read Roy Fielding's thesis to find out. I also recommend a read on ROA (Resource Oriented Architecture), which is somewhat more specific than the concept of REST itself. It is also the most commonly applied of RESTful designs. It's often confused with REST itself.

Comment: A HTTP served website is not targeted at humans as well, but first of all at HTTP browsers ;) So WWW serving hypertext documents *is* a webservice.

Answer (score 4):

1. Correct
2. The W3C defines a "[Web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)" as "a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network".
3. A fully RESTful service is one that adheres to *all* or the architectural constraints as layed out in Roy Fielding's thesis, [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm). It's a long read and there are many interpretations. A good start would be to familiarise yourself with the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). **NOTE:** Most Web Services that claim to be RESTful are only at [level 2](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level2) in that model.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to understand what is a fully RESTful service you have to understand the difference between RESTful services and standard Web Services. It's quite good exaplained in JEE6 Tutorial by Oracle:

> NonRESTful WebServices (In Java as JAX-WS): Big web services use XML messages that
>   follow the Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) standard, an XML language defining a
>   message architecture and message formats. Such systems often contain a machine-readable
>   description of the operations offered by the service, written in the Web Services Description
>   Language (WSDL), an XML language for defining interfaces syntactically.
>   The SOAP message format and the WSDL interface definition language have gained
>   widespread adoption. Many development tools, such as NetBeans IDE, can reduce the
>   complexity of developing web service applications.
>   A SOAP-based design must include the following elements.
>
> ■ A formal contract must be established to describe the interface that the web service offers.
>      WSDL can be used to describe the details of the contract, which may include messages,
>     operations, bindings, and the location of the web service. You may also process SOAP
>    messages in a JAX-WS service without publishing a WSDL.
>
> ■ The architecture must address complex nonfunctional requirements. Many web service
>      specifications address such requirements and establish a common vocabulary for them.
>     Examples include transactions, security, addressing, trust, coordination, and so on.
>
> ■ The architecture needs to handle asynchronous processing and invocation. In such cases,
>      the infrastructure provided by standards, such as Web Services Reliable Messaging
>     (WSRM), and APIs, such as JAX-WS, with their client-side asynchronous invocation
>    support, can be leveraged out of the box.
>
> RESTful Web Services (In Java as JAX-RS)
>   In Java EE 6, JAX-RS provides the functionality for Representational State Transfer (RESTful)
>   web services. REST is well suited for basic, ad hoc integration scenarios. RESTful web services,
>   often better integrated with HTTP than SOAP-based services are, do not require XML messages
>   or WSDL service–API definitions.
>   Project Jersey is the production-ready reference implementation for the JAX-RS specification.
>   Jersey implements support for the annotations defined in the JAX-RS specification, making it
>   easy for developers to build RESTful web services with Java and the Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM).
>
> Types of Web Services
>   Because RESTful web services use existing well-known W3C and Internet Engineering Task
>   Force (IETF) standards (HTTP, XML, URI, MIME) and have a lightweight infrastructure that
>   allows services to be built with minimal tooling, developing RESTful web services is inexpensive
>   and thus has a very low barrier for adoption. You can use a development tool such as NetBeans
>   IDE to further reduce the complexity of developing RESTful web services.
>   A RESTful design may be appropriate when the following conditions are met.
>
> ■ The web services are completely stateless. A good test is to consider whether the interaction
>      can survive a restart of the server.
>
> ■ A caching infrastructure can be leveraged for performance. If the data that the web service
>      returns is not dynamically generated and can be cached, the caching infrastructure that web
>     servers and other intermediaries inherently provide can be leveraged to improve
>    performance. However, the developer must take care because such caches are limited to the
>   HTTP GET method for most servers.
>
> ■ The service producer and service consumer have a mutual understanding of the context and
>      content being passed along. Because there is no formal way to describe the web services
>     interface, both parties must agree out of band on the schemas that describe the data being
>    exchanged and on ways to process it meaningfully. In the real world, most commercial
>   applications that expose services as RESTful implementations also distribute so-called
>   value-added toolkits that describe the interfaces to developers in popular programming
>   languages.
>
> ■ Bandwidth is particularly important and needs to be limited. REST is particularly useful for
>      limited-profile devices, such as PDAs and mobile phones, for which the overhead of headers
>     and additional layers of SOAP elements on the XML payload must be restricted.
>
> ■ Web service delivery or aggregation into existing web sites can be enabled easily with a
>      RESTful style. Developers can use such technologies as JAX-RS and Asynchronous
>     JavaScript with XML (AJAX) and such toolkits as Direct Web Remoting (DWR) to consume
>    the services in their web applications. Rather than starting from scratch, services can be
>   exposed with XML and consumed by HTML pages without significantly refactoring the
>   existing web site architecture. Existing developers will be more productive because they are
>   adding to something they are already familiar with rather than having to start from scratch
>   with new technology.
>
> Deciding Which Type of Web Service to Use
>
> Basically, you would want to use RESTful web services for integration over the web and use big
>   web services in enterprise application integration scenarios that have advanced quality of
>   service (QoS) requirements.
>
> ■ WebServices: addresses advanced QoS requirements commonly occurring in enterprise
>      computing. [..]
>
> ■ RESTfull: makes it easier to write web applications that apply some or all of the constraints of the REST style to induce desirable properties in the application, such as loose coupling
>     (evolving the server is easier without breaking existing clients), scalability (start small and
>    grow), and architectural simplicity (use off-the-shelf components, such as proxies or HTTP
>   routers). You would choose to use JAX-RS for your web application because it is easier for
>   many types of clients to consume RESTful web services while enabling the server side to
>   evolve and scale. Clients can choose to consume some or all aspects of the service and mash
>   it up with other web-based services.